# Consolidating Multiple Columns into one column with a unique identifier - EXCEL

Tags: excel

I want to consolidate multiple columns into one. I have been looking on the internet and there are things that show how to do this, but none have actually worked so far. Best way is to explain what i am trying to do is through an example:

From: Column A: Row 1 to Row 800: Names (Unique). Column B to Column Z: Other Names (Not unique).

When I try and apply a pivot table to organise the data, i find it difficult to filter because Other Names are duplicates.

What I want to do is try is to consolidate Column B to Column Z into one Column. So my outcome will be:

From: Column A: Row 1 to Row xxxx: Names are now duplicates and Column B is consolidated into one column - Other Names which are also Duplicates.

Many Thanks,

Comment: So you want to repeat in column A the value in A1 for every value in row 1 and in column B those same values (this for all values in column A)?

Comment: So basically, in Column A i have Public Listed Company Names, in Column B to Z i have brokers that represent the company. e.g. Column A Row 1: Apple. Column B Row 1: Goldman, Column C Row 1: Morgan Stan. Column D Row 1: JP Morgan etc etc  Now when i try and Pivot that up I can't complete my objective: How many Brokers cover Apple. But If I can consolidate All those brokers into one column I can pivot it up by making those Brokers unique and dropping the number of companies next to them and setting up a count function. That will give me Goldman - 50 companies, MS - 75 companies etc etc

Comment: So it's like: row 1 = Apple | Smith | Johnson because Smith and Johnson are Apple's brokers; row 2 = Microsoft | Smith | Potter because Smith and potter are Microsoft's brocker. And you want it to be like: row 1 = Apple | Smith; row 2 = Apple | Johnson; row 3 = Microsoft | Smith; row 4 = Microsoft | Potter. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes correct. that is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub SubCompactColumns()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim WksNewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DblCounter As Double
    Dim DblRow As Double
    Dim DblColumns As Double
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set RngSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Set RngSource = RngSource.Resize(RngSource.End(xlDown).Row - RngSource.Row + 1, 1)
    Set WksNewSheet = Worksheets.Add
    Set RngTarget = WksNewSheet.Range("A1")
    DblColumns = 26
    
    'Covering the whole RngSource.
    For Each RngCell In RngSource
        
        'Covering all the columns.
        For DblCounter = 1 To DblColumns
            
            'Checking if there is any value to be copied.
            If RngCell.Offset(0, DblCounter).Value <> "" Then
                'Copying the values.
                RngTarget.Offset(DblRow, 0).Value = RngCell.Value
                RngTarget.Offset(DblRow, 1).Value = RngCell.Offset(0, DblCounter).Value
                
                'Shifting DblRow for the new row where to paste the results.
                DblRow = DblRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Report any question you have or bug you have encountered. If, according to your judgment, this answer (or any other) is the best solution to your problem you have the privilege to accept it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).